# my matrix multiplication in OpenGL not as expected

Tags: opengl, matrix

I am debugging a matrix multiplication in OpenGL and I am getting an execpted position vector in the resulting matrix.

Here is my code :

```
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(45,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (GLfloat *)&rot);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(2.0f,2.0f,2.0f);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (GLfloat *)&trs);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glLoadMatrixf(rot);
    glMultMatrixf(trs);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (GLfloat *)&rottrs);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

From the sheer mathematical perspective, I should get 2xcos(45)-2xsin(45) in rottrs[12] and 2xcos(45)+2xsin(45) in rottrs[14]
because rot[0]=cos(45) and rot[2]=-sin(45)

But I am having the inverse. The debugger shows :

rottrs[12]=2.8284271

rottrs[13]=2.0000000

rottrs[14]=0.00000000

rottrs[15]=1.0000000

Could you tell me where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL indices its matrices in column major order, i.e. indices go

```
0 4 8 c
1 5 9 d
2 6 a e
3 7 b f
```

Comment: I know it is column major. But my question is about the values at the 3th and bth (using your indices) elements. The 3th, for instance, should be 0; the result of 2xcos(45)-2xsin(45).Thanks.